# Invalidating an Ember Simple Auth session while testing

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth, teaspoon

Typically, when you invalidate an Ember Simple Auth session, it'll reload the application. This is great for security in production, but while testing, it can be a headache. I'm running my tests using Teaspoon, and any time I logout a test user, Ember Simple Auth reloads the app--essentially terminating the test suite.

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just override the `sessionInvalidationSucceeded` action of your application route in test mode so it doesn't replace the location.

Comment: That works. For anyone else looking into this, this method is in the `ApplicationRouteMixin`. This means you can change it with something like: `Ember.SimpleAuth.ApplicationRouteMixin.reopen({ actions: { sessionInvalidationSucceeded: function() {} } });`

Comment: Or you just change the actual application route.